# How to use Moralis Plugins in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, moralis

I'm currently using Moralis version `2.0.1` and `await Moralis.initPlugins();` doesn't seem to work on my end. I logged the Moralis package and I found this:

```
default: {
    Core: MoralisCore {
      modules: [Modules],
      config: [Config],
      logger: [LoggerController],
      name: 'core',
      registerModules: [Function (anonymous)],
      registerModule: [Function (anonymous)],
      getModule: [Function (anonymous)],
      start: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    Auth: MoralisAuth {
      name: 'auth',
      core: [MoralisCore],
      type: 'api',
      logger: [LoggerController],
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      baseUrl: 'https://auth-api.do-prod-1.moralis.io',
      requestMessage: [Function (anonymous)],
      verify: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    EvmApi: MoralisEvmApi {
      name: 'evmApi',
      core: [MoralisCore],
      type: 'api',
      logger: [LoggerController],
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      baseUrl: 'https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2',
      endpoints: [Endpoints],
      native: [Object],
      account: [Object],
      resolve: [Object],
      defi: [Object],
      token: [Object],
      _info: [Object],
      info: [Object],
      storage: [Object]
    },
    SolApi: MoralisSolApi {
      name: 'solApi',
      core: [MoralisCore],
      type: 'api',
      logger: [LoggerController],
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      baseUrl: 'https://solana-gateway.moralis.io',
      endpoints: [Endpoints],
      account: [Object],
      nft: [Object]
    },
    start: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

I can't seem to find initPlugins nor Plugins. I was planning to use the opensea plugin, how can I do that on version `2.0.1`? Most of the resources I found on Google are from 2021 so I assume there had been a lot of changes, I haven't found anything that's recent. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will need to use the [moralis-v1 SDK](https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/connect-the-sdk) to interact with your Moralis server plugins, instead of Moralis 2.0.1 which doesn't involve Moralis servers.